# Installing ANT on appcelerator

Tags: java, android, ant, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having trouble right clicking a build.xml and running as ant, there is a current bug with appcelerator and building modules and this seems to be the only work around i can find, especially as i got told the next update will be February and i have clients that the app doesn't run on 6.0.0.
[this is the suggested workaroud](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23502)

i can get ant working for eclipse but any ideas how to install to appcelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my question here: [Duplicate entry: org/appcelerator/titanium/gen/bindings.json in custom Android module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953652/duplicate-entry-org-appcelerator-titanium-gen-bindings-json-in-custom-android-m)
I have a workaround where you open the generated jar and just remove the gen/bindings.json

You can run `ant` from the command line inside the android folder of your module to build it. Then open the zip/jar file and remove the .json. 
This way you can use your module. Just remember to remove the file again if you rebuild the module.